# Weaker definition of limit for a function with a countable infinite number of poles

Tags: limits, continuity

Before starting, I anticipate that I do not have a very strong mathematical background. I will use an example to show my problem and I am asking if it rings a bell for a concept already existing.

Let's take the function
$$f_p (x) = \frac{1}{1 - \sin ^{2p} \ln x}$$
with *p* being any natural number. This function as an infinite number of vertical asymptotes given at the pole of the denominator in $x = \exp(\frac{\pi n}{2})$, with *n* also a natural number, more and more distant one another.
If *p* is big enough, $f_p (x)$ will be almost always 1, except for a very tiny interval around the poles of the denominator.

Now, let's consider the limit
$$ \lim _{x \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{f_p(x) }{x}$$

Clearly this limit does not exist because of the infinite amount of vertical asymptotes.
However, it is also clear that as x grows the function lies almost always around 0 up to few, limited, intervals.
This reminds me (vaguely) of the difference between the Riemann integral and the Lipschitz integral, where in the latter you can omit a numerable set of points from the integration domain without changing the result.

Is there a weaker definition of limit that would fit this case?

Comment: There are definitions of $\liminf$ and $\limsup$. For example $\liminf_{t\rightarrow\infty} \cos(t) = -1$ and $\limsup_{t\rightarrow\infty} \cos(t) = 1$. Of course, in your case you would need to define $f_p(x)$ for all $x>0$ for the limit as $x\rightarrow \infty$ to make sense. I guess you can define the poles to take value $\infty$ so then the $\limsup$ of $f_p(x)/x$ is $\infty$ and the $\liminf$ is $0$.

Comment: @Michael Thank you for your answer but it does not help that much. I am familiar with these definitions, and my case was mostly a toy example, in real live I have several vertical asymptotes where the function goes to $+\infty$ on one side and $-\infty$ on the other

Comment: You may want to integrate.